# Choice of Convolution Operator in Spatial Transformation Networks for Point Clouds

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, point-clouds

In many deep learning models for shape analysis, the input image/shape is first going through some Spatial Transform Network (STN) to align the input to a constant canonical space for better model learning and performance. I am also considering including a STN in my application, which takes inputs of 3D points clouds, so I am building a STN for point clouds.

Then, I try to reference from some existing models.
For example, here is the beginning part (the localization network part) of the [STN in PointNet](https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet/blob/master/models/transform_nets.py):

```
def input_transform_net(point_cloud, is_training, bn_decay=None, K=3):
    """ Input (XYZ) Transform Net, input is BxNx3 gray image
        Return:
            Transformation matrix of size 3xK """
    batch_size = point_cloud.get_shape()[0].value
    num_point = point_cloud.get_shape()[1].value

    input_image = tf.expand_dims(point_cloud, -1)
    net = tf_util.conv2d(input_image, 64, [1,3],
                         padding='VALID', stride=[1,1],
                         bn=True, is_training=is_training,
                         scope='tconv1', bn_decay=bn_decay)
    net = tf_util.conv2d(net, 128, [1,1],
                         padding='VALID', stride=[1,1],
                         bn=True, is_training=is_training,
                         scope='tconv2', bn_decay=bn_decay)
    net = tf_util.conv2d(net, 1024, [1,1],
                         padding='VALID', stride=[1,1],
                         bn=True, is_training=is_training,
                         scope='tconv3', bn_decay=bn_decay)
    net = tf_util.max_pool2d(net, [num_point,1],
                             padding='VALID', scope='tmaxpool')

    # and more...
```

Please let me try to summarize the steps taken here (hope I am making it right here):

```
1. expand input image so dimensions change from:  
    BxNx3 --> BxNx3x1.
2. 1st conv. op. has kernel size [1,3], so after 1st conv. the dimensions of image should be:   
    BxNx3x1 --> BxNx1x64
3. 2nd conv. op. has kernel size [1,1], so after 2nd conv. the dimensions of image should be:   
    BxNx1x64 --> BxNx1x128
4. ... and it goes on.
```

Just for my curiosity, I am wondering with the settings following would be equivalent as the one adopted in PointNet (shown above), as well as many other models.

1. I am wondering here if it will be equivalent if I replace Conv2d by Conv1d, and change it to something like:

```
# Input dimension: BxNx3
# not expanding dims this time
net = input_image

# After 1st conv. dims:  BxNx3 --> BxNx64
net = conv1d(net, 64, kernel_size=[1], stride=[1], ...)
# After 2nd conv. dims:  BxNx64 --> BxNx128
net = conv1d(net, 64, kernel_size=[1], stride=[1], ...)
# ... and it goes on.
```

2. Coming from the first setting, I am also wondering if the conv. op. here is actually equivalent to some matrix multiplication/fully connected layer (as in tensorflow)/linear layer (as in torch):

```
# Reshape input dims: BxNx3 --> (B*N)x3
# so data entries in the batch are "stacked together".
net = input_image.reshape(-1, 3)

# I use torch.nn.linear() from pytorch here for easy explanation.
# which basically does the follows:

# After 1st linear:  (B*N)x3 --> (B*N)x64
net = torch.nn.linear(net, in_feat=3, out_feat=64)
# After 2nd linear:  (B*N)x64 --> (B*N)x128
net = torch.nn.linear(net, in_feat=64, out_feat=128)
# ... and it goes on.
```

I actually prefer the second setting, if it is correct, because the first dimension of input image can be replaced by something like (N_1+N_2+...+N_B) instead of B*N. This means that I do not have to fix every data entry to have the same size. Of course, it this setting is correct.